# Xamarin Forms vertically align labels of different font sizes to the same baseline

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, vertical-alignment

I have two labels side by side in a horizontally oriented stack layout. The labels have different font sizes. I would like to make the baseline (bottom edge) of each label text the same regardless of the font size. However the default behaviour of xamarin forms is not to do that. The following code

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label  FontSize="12" Text="A Noble Spirit"></Label>
            <Label  FontSize="18" Text="Embiggens The Smallest Man"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

Results in the following view running on android.

[image: Figure 1, different baseline for labels of different font size]

I've tried many different combinations of setting the vertical text alignment and the vertical options attributes on the labels. The best I've been able to come up with (and what I think should work) is adding vertical options = end to them both. This improves things a bit but there's still a mismatch, so that the bigger label's text (embiggens) starts higher up than the smaller label - like so:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="12" Text="A Noble Spirit"></Label>
            <Label VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="18" Text="Embiggens The Smallest Man"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image: Figure, good but not great]

As you can see, somewhat of an improvement, but still not aligned. This is driving me up the wall a bit. I'm starting to think it may be a bug in Xamarin Forms for android. (I'll add to this question later when I can get an example running on iOS to see if it's android specific.).

I CAN hack it to sort of work by adding top margin to the smaller label that is equal to the difference in font size, which is gross and I don't want to introduce that technical debt and upkeep into my system. But here it is to show it. Hoping not to have to resort to this...

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label FontSize="12" Margin="0,6,0,0" Text="A Noble Spirit"></Label>
            <Label FontSize="18" Text="Embiggens The Smallest Man"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image: Figure 3, Hacky Sack]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:** If you set the background color of two labels ,you can see that because label has a default "Padding" . The value depends on its height .

[image]

**Solution:**

You can put two different strings in the same Label. It has the property called **FormattedText** ,which allows you to  set the formatted text for the Label .

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label FormattedText="{Binding FormattedTextContent}" x:Name="label" ></Label>
        <Label FormattedText="{Binding FormattedTextContent}" x:Name="label2" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

in code behind

```
FormattedTextContent = new FormattedString();
var fs = new FormattedString();
fs.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "A Noble Spirit " , FontSize = 12, TextColor = Color.Black });
fs.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "  ", FontSize = 18 });
label.FormattedText = fs;

var fs1 = new FormattedString();

fs.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "  ", FontSize = 12 });
fs.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "Embiggens The Smallest Man", TextColor = Color.Black, FontSize = 18 });
label2.FormattedText = fs1;
```

Of course you can use MVVM because it is a bindable property .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. I can get it working like this when the two formatted strings are in a single sentence. However for my use case I need to position the strings separately - one centre aligned in the centre of a view, and one right aligned in the same view. Is there a way I can do that using the formatted text approach given that I can't use horizontal options on the individual spans?

Comment: Check my update answer , it use two different labels so that you can set the position .

Comment: Nice, so basically we add a blank span with a single space with the font size of the other span which forces the lines to be the same height. It works well, and seems a bit less hacky than the margin solution. I still think there could be an option for this in forms, but in the absence of that I'll use this one. Cheers!

Comment: Lucas, any idea how to achieve this to align the label texts at their centre? The trick only seems to work for baseline.